# Percentage difference from previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to add a percent difference column to my data as i'm showing the last 3 years of sales and commissions in my query and want percent of difference for each salesperson listed to show the difference in the amounts that were made for sales and also for commission from the previous year in that same month. So for the amount made in January 2017 for commission and sales, I want to show whether they had an increase or decrease in the amount between what was earned in January 2018 compared to what was earned in January 2017.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    'ABC' AS CompanyCode, 
    ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, 
    ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, 
    ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, 
    SUM(ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceTotalSum, 
    SUM(ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.CommissionAmt) AS CommissionAmtSum, 
    DATENAME(month, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS Month, 
    DATENAME(year, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS Year, 
    DATEPART(m, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS MonthNumber
FROM
    ABC.AR_Customer INNER JOIN
    ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission ON 
        ABC.AR_Customer.ARDivisionNo = ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.ARDivisionNo AND 
        ABC.AR_Customer.CustomerNo = ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.CustomerNo INNER JOIN
    ABC.AR_Salesperson ON 
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo = ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonDivisionNo AND 
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo = ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonNo
GROUP BY 
    ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, 
    ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, 
    ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, 
    DATENAME(month, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), 
    DATENAME(year, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), 
    DATEPART(m, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate)
HAVING
    (DATENAME(year, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) > DATEADD(year, - 4, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY 
    SalespersonName, 
    Year, 
    MonthNumber
```

Tried various ways to get the data to do this but haven't been able to, like using OVER PARTITION BY and all that. Desired Results and Sample Data are in the link below.

[image: Desired Results and Sample Data]

Comment: Have you had a look at the `LEAD`/`LAG` functions? What have you tried?

Comment: have a look here: this page contains the solution of your problem.
https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/

Comment: Didn't you post this question earlier today?

Comment: @Larnu I tried those two functions, but it only goes either the previous row or next row. How do I get it to go based on the month, year, and salesperson name

Comment: David, please provide DDL+DML (queries to create the table(s) and insert the sample data)

Comment: @RonenAriely 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
 [CompanyCode] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [SalespersonName] [varchar](30) NULL,
 [SalespersonDivisionNo] [varchar](2) NULL,
 [InvoiceTotalSum] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
 [CommissionAmtSum] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
 [Month] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
 [Year] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
 [MonthNumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE and JOIN to it using the previous year:

```
; WITH L4Y
AS (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
        'ABC' AS CompanyCode, 
        ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, 
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, 
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, 
        SUM(ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceTotalSum, 
        SUM(ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.CommissionAmt) AS CommissionAmtSum, 
        DATENAME(month, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS Month, 
        DATENAME(year, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS Year, 
        DATEPART(m, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS MonthNumber
    FROM
        ABC.AR_Customer INNER JOIN
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission ON 
            ABC.AR_Customer.ARDivisionNo = ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.ARDivisionNo AND 
            ABC.AR_Customer.CustomerNo = ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.CustomerNo INNER JOIN
        ABC.AR_Salesperson ON 
            ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo = ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonDivisionNo AND 
            ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo = ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonNo
    GROUP BY 
        ABC.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, 
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, 
        ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, 
        DATENAME(month, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), 
        DATENAME(year, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), 
        DATEPART(m, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate)
    HAVING
        (DATENAME(year, ABC.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) > DATEADD(year, - 4, GETDATE()))
    )
SELECT L4Y.*
    , InvoiceTotalPrevYear = COALESCE(LY.InvoiceTotalSum, 0)
    , CommissionAmtSumPrevYear = COALESCE(LY.CommissionAmtSum, 0)
FROM L4Y
    LEFT JOIN L4Y LY
        ON L4Y.CompanyCode = LY.CompanyCode
        AND L4Y.SalespersonName = LY.SalespersonName
        --...(join on ALL fields except YEAR)
        AND l4y.[Month] = LY.[Month]
        -- Here's where the magic happens:
        AND L4Y.[Year] = (LY.[Year]-1) ;
```